# Django {% if %} statement

Tags: django, forms, model, display

I have a form that allows users to upload an image as well as an image url. Depending on which they use the image src on the page should be the uploaded image, or the image from the URL.

Here's the form:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'url', 'product_type', 'price', 'image', 'image_url']
        labels = {
            'name': 'Product Name',
            'url': 'Product URL',
            'product_type': 'Product Type',
            'description': 'Product Description',
            'image': 'Product Image',
            'image_url': 'Product Image URL',
            'price': 'Product Price'
        }
        widgets = {
            'description': Textarea(attrs={'rows': 5}),
        }
```

I have two issues to sort out. The first one is, on the page where the image needs to be displayed I have the following:

```
<img class="img-fluid" {% if product.image.url %}src="{{ product.image.url }}" {% else %} src="{{ product.image_url }}" {% endif %} alt="" />
```

Only the "product.image.url" images show up.  I think I'm confusing myself here so am asking for help.

The second thing is only allowing users to upload and image OR use an image URL - that next on the list but, for now, I want to work out how to get this issue sorted out.

Comment: Is src empty for product.image_url?

Comment: So far it's either image.url or image_url - not both - does that make sense?

Comment: I just don't understand the question. Do you mean that product.image_url value does not appear in html or it appears but image is not shown?

Comment: If an image exists (product.image.url) it pulls the image from the /static/images folder and shows the image on the page.  If there is no image it is supposed to show the the image URL, which is an external link to an image (product.image_url), If that exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show external link to the image and not the image itself then you can:

```
{% if product.image.url %}
<img class="img-fluid" src="{{ product.image.url }}" alt="" />
{% else %} 
   {% if product.image_url %}
      <a href="{{ product.image_url }}">{{ product.image_url }}</a>
   {% else %}
      <a href="">{{ product.image_url }}>Sorry, no link for image!</a>
   {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks - but the point is, if a local image isn't available <img src={{ product.image.url } />} then the external image is pulled in <img src={{ product.image_url }} />.  Right now a user can upload an image and input an external image url - once I solve this issue I will be putting in logic that only one can be used.

Comment: Sorry, but with different comments you contradict yourself, that is why the problem is not clear for me

Comment: Probably you didnt notice that i dont have src={{product.image_url}} in my code?

Comment: I've said the same thing over again - if there isn't a local img, it looks for the remote image - your code does exactly the same as mine.

Comment: It does not, but ok. Consider checking it line by line one more time. In my opinion, it is exact logic you described in last question comment.

Comment: Here's what's happening - if the page sees no image uploaded it puts a default image in its place. For the most part this works:

       {% if product.image.url %}
         <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ product.image.url }}" />
        {% else %}
         <img class="display-none" />
        {% endif %}

        {% if product.image_url %}
         <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ product.image_url }}" />
        {% else %}
         <img class="display-none" />
        {% endif %}

but the default image is showing, as well as product.image_url.  I need to hide the default image